# $concat on aggregate mongodb

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

This a little bit confusing. 
I am trying to `$group` the result of the `aggregatation` and while `grouping` them I create new field which consists of concation of two different fields. Hmm. Actually I was not willing to share the structure of database and confuse you. But the description is not explanatory.

So here we go.

student collection

```
{id: "1", school: "georgia tech"}
```

university collection

```
{name: "georgia tech" , state: "Georgia" , city: "Atlanta"}
```

What I want to get? I want to get

```
{id: 1, name: "georgia tech" , place: "Georgia_Atlanta"}
```

What have I done to achieve this?

```
db.student.aggregate([
    {$match: {"id": "1"}},
    {$lookup: {from: "university" , localField: "school" , foreignField: "name", as: "document"}},
    {$group: {_id: "$id", name: {$push: "$school"}, place: {$push: {$concat: ["$document.state" , "_" , "$document.city"]}}}}   
])
```

But this throws an error as;

```
assert: command failed: {
    "ok" : 0,
    "errmsg" : "$concat only supports strings, not Array",
    "code" : 16702
}
```

In the meantime;

```
db.student.aggregate([
    {$match: {"id": "1"}},
    {$lookup: {from: "university" , localField: "school" , foreignField: "name", as: "document"}},
    {$group: {_id: "$id", name: {$push: "$school"}, place: {$push: "$document.state" }}}    
])
```

returns as;

```
{ "_id" : "1", "name" : [ "georgia tech" ], "place" : [ [ "Georgia" ] ] }
```

The problem is concating the `state` and `city` fields.
So here the question again. How can I concat `document.state`, `_` and `document.city`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[**`$lookup`**](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/#pipe._S_lookup) returns an array so you need to use the [**`$arrayElemAt`**](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/arrayElemAt/#exp._S_arrayElemAt) operator to flatten it (if it has a single element) or **[`$unwind`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/#pipe._S_unwind)** (if it has multiple elements). So in the end, you should be able to run the following pipeline to get the desired result:

```
db.student.aggregate([
    { "$match": { "id": "1" } },
    {
        "$lookup": {
            "from": "university", 
            "localField": "school", 
            "foreignField": "name", 
            "as": "document"
        }
    },
    {
        "$project": {
            "id": 1,
            "university": { "$arrayElemAt": [ "$document", 0 ] }
        }
    },
    {
        "$project": {
            "id": 1,
            "name": "$university.name",
            "place": { "$concat": ["$university.state", "_", "$university.city"] }
        }
    }    
])
```

Answer (score 1):

I do not know the exact usecase, but if you need to use GroupBy, this is working version. Otherwise, chridam is using simplier approach :

```
db.student.aggregate([
    {$match: {"id": "1"}},
    {$lookup: {from: "university" , localField: "school" , foreignField: "name", as: "document"}},
    {$group: {_id: "$id", name: {$first: "$school"}, tempplace: {$first: "$document" }}},
    {$unwind: "$tempplace"},
    {$project: {id: 1, name: 1, place: {$concat: ["$tempplace.state", "_", "$tempplace.city"]}}}
])
```